# How do I insert SQL server values using C#? I keep getting null

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, null

I recently viewed a youtube tutorial on how to use a c#-class to  run sql-commands and fetch data. This is the tutorial I have followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WG3Hwk7Yp48#t=13m42s at 13:42 you can see that he runs his code, inserts name-values into a textbox and is then able to show the new values in the combobox.

However, whenever I run my code I get this error (fullsize image available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM405.png)):

[image]

The table I am trying to collect/insert data from has a 'unr' int which cannot be null, and a name which is a varchar.

This is my SQL-DAL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
class DAL
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter da;
    private DataTable dt;

    public DAL()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=VIKTOR-PC;Initial Catalog=HT2015;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
    }

    public void SqlQuery(string queryText)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, con);
    }

    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    public void NoQueryEx()
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and this is my form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WindowsFormsApplication3.DAL con;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new DAL();
        con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO dbo.Users(name) VALUES (@NameP)");
        con.cmd.Parameters.Add("@NameP", textBox1.Text);
        con.NoQueryEx();
        con.SqlQuery("SELECT name FROM Users");
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach(DataRow dr in con.QueryEx().Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now it keeps saying that unr is null, and all I want is to add new names to the table. I havent got a clue on how to solve this.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?  It says you can't insert `NULL` for `unr`, and by not specifying it in your `INSERT` statement that's exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do understand the error, but I feel that there has to be some way to just add in new names or have the unr auto-generated. From an application standpoint it would be weird for the user to type in a unr and a name (restaurant table reservation). Is there any way to have the unr autogenerated and have the user enter the name manually?

Comment: As Andy Korneyev says in his answer, just give it a default value at the table definition.

Comment: I've added a default value to the table now but it keeps telling me that it can't be set to null. http://i.imgur.com/BFKtDVB.png

Do I have to modify my insert-string? Why does it work for the guy in the youtube-tutorial?

Comment: @user2925033 in my answer by "having default value" I mean not default value in .NET DataTable, but in SQL table on server. The fact you've added some default value in your client's code DataTable definition doesn't matter since you are still doesn't insert anything into `unr` in your sql query. So if `1` is your default value - just launch SQL Management Studio, open your database, find `Users` table and set this as default to `unr` column.

Answer (score 1):

Your table `Users` has **not-nullable** column `unr`.

But this query you're using:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users(name) VALUES (@NameP)
```

doesn't inserts anything into `unr` - this is the reason you're getting that exception.

You should either insert something into `unr` in your query or make it nullable (or having some default value) at table definition.